# Haskell school of expression fix function

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, infinite, fixpoint-combinators

So I am reading Paul Hudak's book "The Haskell School of Expression" and am stuck on an exercise in there.

Here it goes

*Suppose function fix is defined as*

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

*What is the principal type of `fix`?* That one I know, it's `b -> b -> b`

But I don't understand the way `fix` is defined, won't it go into an infinite recursion?

Also, *let the `remainder` function be defined as*

```
remainder :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
remainder a b = if a < b then a 
                else remainder (a - b) b
```

*Rewrite `remainder` using `fix` so that it is non-recursive.*

Comment: The type of `fix` is not `b -> b -> b`.

Comment: no, it's `(b -> b) -> b`.

Comment: I added a missing `then` to your `if`. Otherwise, your `remainder` function is not valid Haskell...

Comment: Haskell uses lazy evaluation. `f (fix f)` calls the outer `f` first, not `fix`.

Comment: For many functions `fix` will indeed go into infinite recursion without returning. However for many it wont. For example `fix (const 1)` or `fix (1:)`.

Comment: How would it not go into infinite recursion for (const 1) and (1:)

Comment: `take 3 (fix (1:))` == `[1,1,1]`. `fix (const 1) = 1`.

Comment: @AbdulRahman Try to evaluate it by hand with pen and paper.

Comment: Nice I see it for (1:) and (const 1). Its haskell's lazy evaluation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the principal type of fix is actually `(b -> b) -> b` (remember that only `b -> (b -> b)` is the same as `b -> b -> b`).

In a strict language, such a definition would go into infinite recursion, but because Haskell is lazy, the arguments to a function are evaluated only if they are at any point needed. For example you can define `factorial`.

```
-- with recursion
factorial :: Int -> Int
factorial n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * factorial (n-1)

-- with `fix`
factorial' :: Int -> Int
factorial' = fix (\f n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * f (n - 1))
```

Following the same pattern, you should be able to define `remainder`.

Answer (score 2):

Playing with it a little gives us

```
fix f         = f (fix f)                                            -- definition
fix f     a   = f (fix f) a                                          -- eta expansion
fix f     a b = f (fix f) a b                                        -- eta expansion
remainder a b = if a < b then a else remainder (a - b) b             -- definition
-- we want  remainder = fix f:                                       -- equation
fix f     a b = if a < b then a else (fix f)   (a - b) b             -- substitution
       = (\g -> if a < b then a else g         (a - b) b) (fix f)    -- abstraction
   = fix (\g -> \a b -> if a < b then a else g (a - b) b) a b        -- abstraction
```

thus

```
remainder = 
     fix (\g     a b -> if a < b then a else g (a - b) b)            -- eta reduction
```